# Gmail API - body of the message contains dash and can't be base64 decoded

Tags: java, base64, gmail-api

I have response from Gmail API encoded in base64.

I used `com.google.api.client.util.Base64` to decode this response, and it worked fine.

Now I'm refactoring code and want to update versions of dependencies. I noticed that Base64 class is now deprecated and it's suggested to use `com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding`. However, when I do the following:

```
Message asdf = service.users().messages().get(gmailUser, message.getId()).execute();
List<MessagePartHeader> headers = asdf.getPayload().getHeaders();
String data = asdf.getPayload().getBody().getData();
String body = new String(BaseEncoding.base64().decode(data));
```

I get an error:

```
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding$DecodingException: Unrecognized character: -
```

And indeed, I have some dashes in data that I'm receiving.

Is this a bug in Gmail API? Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

I shouldn't use `BaseEncoding.base64().decode(data)`, but `BaseEncoding.base64Url().decode(data)`.